# How can I determine if a 2015 Nissan Leaf can be monitored/controlled via an app?

Tags: computer, electric-vehicle, leaf

I've seen in reviews that Nissan Leaf's have a phone app that can monitor and control its charging and climate functions. For example, you can view on your phone how much power the car's battery has, you can set it to charge only to a given percent or set it to charge within a certain time frame, you can be notified when it is charged to X percent, and you can even set the climate controls in the car to turn on at a certain time while charging so the car is warmed up with a fresh charge when you get in to drive it.

Thing is I'm having trouble determining if a specific car has this ability. A dealership selling a used 2015 didn't know. I have the VIN and specs but it isn't clear on this point. This particular vehicle has Bluetooth and the spec sheet says "smart device integration" but the console itself seems pretty low-tech with a small non-touch display that I could only get to show audio info during a test drive. This particular model is a 2015 Nissan Leaf S but has some upgrades such as a charging package (e.g. quick charge port, [**maybe**](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/43518/does-a-nissan-leaf-necessarily-have-a-6-6kw-capacity-on-board-charger-if-it-has) advanced on-board charger) and winter package (e.g. heated seats and steering wheel).

Does anyone know if 2015 Nissan Leaf's can have their charging and climate functions controlled via a phone app? How do you know, and what's the app?

Comment: Have you looked in the owner's manual? If the feature is available on the car, standard or optional, the manual should cover it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nissan used to have an app called *CarWings* for the purpose you describe. Problems with it getting [hacked](https://www.usatoday.com/story/tech/news/2016/02/24/nissan-disables-app-hacked-electric-leaf-smart-phone-troy-hunt/80882756/) caused Nissan to disable that software and move to an app called [*NissanConnect EV*](https://www.nissanusa.com/connect/faq).

Unfortunately, *NissanConnect EV* is not backward compatible to cars that were originally equipped with *CarWings* (your car). Therefore, there is not an app available to your for the purpose of remote controlling your 2015 Leaf.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late to the game here, but just FYI, the S-trimmed LEAF (base trim, available 2013-2017) didn't come with any sort of telematics -- hacked, abandoned, or otherwise. Also the Bluetooth is phone-only, so no wireless jams for you!

My 2015 S has a USB port wired to the sound system, but it's only compatible with iPhone. So if you have an Android, you're stuck with the analog Aux port.