# Does a Nissan Leaf necessarily have a 6.6kW capacity on-board charger if it has Quick Charge port?

Tags: nissan, electric-vehicle, battery-charger, leaf

Looking at a 2015 Nissan Leaf I see it has a Quick Charge port (listed as part of the Charge Package on the spec sheet). Does this mean this car also has the 6.6kW on board charger?

I'm not sure if you can have one without the other, which is why I ask, and I want to know whether the regular charger on this car is limited to 3.3kW charging or if it can potentially handle 6.6kW charging. The dealer didn't know when I asked.

Comment: My 2011 Nissan leaf does have such capability so yours should .The onboard charger changes its capacity according to the Power plug .I am down to 10 bars now .The car has 130,000Km .I have not so far needed to fast charge .If you fast charge occasionaly it wont matter but all the time it is risky .It has been said that fast charging is like smoking big cigars .

Comment: lol nice analogy with the big cigars @Autistic. Your comment sounds like a fair answer to me, and if you post it as one I'll check it off if nobody else reminds in a few days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm driving a 2015 LEAF in S (base) trim. It has a CHAdeMO port and 6.6kW L2 charging.

The 2011 and 2012 LEAFs (like David B's) all had 3.3kW L2 charging, CHAdeMO or not. However, starting in 2013, CHAdeMO was an option on the S trim, standard on the SV and SL trim. And if you have CHAdeMO, you have 6.6kW L2.

Answer (score 2):

My 2011 Leaf has CHAdeMO rapid charging but has a 3.3kW internal charger for AC. So, having rapid charge is no guarantee of having the built-in 6.6kW charger.